# Any ideas on what type of image formatting this might be?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, image-formats

A program which written in C++ is sending an image to my node.js server, unfortunately I dont have access to the C++ code. My goal is to display this image on my front end, Ive tried doing so by doing a .toString('base64') call on the data but this didnt work. Heres what the data looks like when I write it to file vs when i perform a for loop and do a .toStrng(). **Any ideas** on what the image format is?
[image]
After performing the following code

```
for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
                        wstream.write(image[i].toString());
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try opening it with something like BlessHexEdit or other binary editor and you will probably see it in the beginning of the file.

Comment: The first few bytes are likely to contain some kind of "tag" that tells you what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code on this page can be used to determine the image type:

http://oroboro.com/image-format-magic-bytes/

The first few bytes of the file are different between image formats, the formats you're looking for are listed in that page.